# How to execute a form(GET method) which is present in a fragement using AJAX and springboot

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The fragments is getting loaded properly. But because the form is not getting executed properly i cannot fetch the values from controller->service->repo. There is no issue in service or repo layer.

```
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                           <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active"  href="#labChart" data-toggle="tab" >1.Lab Charts</a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"  href="#labReport" data-toggle="tab">2.Lab Reports</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

Tab Contents:

```
<div class="tab-content">
                            
                                  <div class="active tab-pane" id="labChart">
                                        <th:block th:replace="labmodals/labChart :: labChart"></th:block> 
                                  </div>
                                  
                                  <div class="tab-pane" id="labReport">
                                        <th:block th:replace="labmodals/labReport :: labReport"></th:block>
                                  </div>
                                  
                          </div>
```

Ajax logic:

```
<script type="module">
    import { VerticalBarChartCreator } from './admin/custom/chartCreator/VerticalBarChartCreator.js';
      
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Check if the 'Lab Charts' tab is active on page load and load content if it is
    loadContentForActiveTab();

    // Attach event listener for tab changes
    $('a.nav-link').on('click', function() 
    {
        // Check if the clicked tab is 'Lab Charts'
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) 
        {
            loadContentForActiveTab();
        }
    });

    function loadContentForActiveTab()
     {
        // Find the active tab
        var activeTab = $('a.nav-link.active').attr('href');
        
        // Load content for 'Lab Charts' tab if it is active
        if (activeTab === "#labChart") 
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: './labChartFragment', // Adjust to your endpoint
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(response) 
                {
                    $(activeTab).html(response);
                    
                    // After successfully loading the form, submit it
                    submitLabForm();
                },
                error: function() 
                {
                    alert("Error loading the lab chart content.");
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
    function submitLabForm() 
    {
        var form = $('#labFormBeanChart');
        
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'), // Get the action attribute of the form
            type: 'GET', // Change to the method of your form if necessary
            data: form.serialize(), // Serialize form data for submission
            success: function(response) 
            {
                 console.log(url,data);
                // Log success message and response to the console
                console.log("Form submitted successfully.", response);
                updateCharts(); // Placeholder for chart updating logic
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                // Log error information to the console
                console.error("Error submitting the form: ", textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
    
    function updateCharts()
    {
        // SAMPLE COLLECTION CHART LOGIC called here START 
        var sampleCollectChartLabels = document.getElementById("sampleCollectChartLabels");
        var sampleCollectChartData = document.getElementById("sampleCollectChartData");
        var sampleCollectChartName = `sampleCollectChart`; //This has to be same as the id present in the canvas
        var sampleCollectChartColor = ['#4b77a9', '#B27200', '#00c0ef','#5f255f','#d21243'];
        var sampleCollectHoverDescription= `Sample Collect`;
        var sampleCollectByOfficeUrlLogic=`./sampleCollectInfoWithOffice?OfficeName=`;
        
        VerticalBarChartCreator(sampleCollectChartLabels,sampleCollectChartData,sampleCollectChartName,sampleCollectChartColor,sampleCollectHoverDescription,sampleCollectByOfficeUrlLogic);
    
    
        // ACCESSION CHART LOGIC called here START 
        var accessionChartLabels = document.getElementById("accessAcknwldgChartLabels");
        var accessionChartData = document.getElementById("accessAcknwldgChartData");
        var accessionChartName = `accessAcknwldgChart`; //This has to be same as the id present in the canvas
        var accessCollectChartColor = ['#4b77a9', '#B27200', '#00c0ef','#5f255f','#d21243'];
        var accessionHoverDescription= `Accession`;
        var accessionByOfficeUrlLogic=`./accessAcknwldgInfoWithOffice?OfficeName=`;
        
        VerticalBarChartCreator(accessionChartLabels,accessionChartData,accessionChartName,accessCollectChartColor,accessionHoverDescription,accessionByOfficeUrlLogic);
    }
    
});
</script>
```

Controller Logic:

```
@GetMapping("/labStatistics")
    public String getLabStatisticsPage(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("labFormBean", new LabFormBean());
        model.addAttribute("brtFormBean", new BrtFormBean());
        model.addAttribute("LabOfficeDateFilter",ls.getLabOfficeDetailsFilter());
        model.addAttribute("officeDateFilter",bs.getOfficeDetailsFilter());
        return "./labStatistics";
    }

    @GetMapping("/labChartFragment")
    public String getLabChartFragment(Model model) {
        // Add any necessary attributes to the model here
        model.addAttribute("labFormBean", new LabFormBean());
        return "labmodals/labChart :: labChart"; // This returns the fragment
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/labChart")
    public String getLabChartPage(@ModelAttribute LabFormBean labFormBean, Model model,
                                  @RequestParam(name= "lang", required = false) String lang,
                                  HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        //model.addAttribute("labFormBean", new LabFormBean());
        model.addAttribute("LabOfficeDateFilter",ls.getLabOfficeDetailsFilter());
        

        if (labFormBean.getLabSdate() != null && labFormBean.getLabEdate() != null)
        {
            sDate = labFormBean.getLabSdate();
            eDate = labFormBean.getLabEdate();
        } 
        else
        {
            sDate = CurrentDate();
            eDate = CurrentDate();
        }

        if (labFormBean.getLabOid() != 0) 
        {
            ofcId = labFormBean.getLabOid();
        } 
        else 
        {
            ofcId = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("================== LAB CHART CONTROLLER layer called ==================" );
        System.out.println("sDate====" + sDate);
        System.out.println("eDate====" + eDate);
        System.out.println("ofcId====" + ofcId);
        
        String urlWithArabic = createUrlWithLang(request, "ar");
        model.addAttribute("urlWithArabic", urlWithArabic);
          
        String urlWithEnglish = createUrlWithLang(request, "en");
        model.addAttribute("urlWithEnglish", urlWithEnglish);
        
    
        model.addAttribute("sampleCollectChart",lcs.getLabSampleCollectionOfficeCountRange(sDate, eDate, ofcId));
        System.out.println("========= SAMPLE COLLECTION CHART SERVICE LOGIC called =========" );
        
        model.addAttribute("accessAcknwldgChart",lcs.getLabAccessionAcknwldgOfficeCountRange(sDate, eDate, ofcId));
        System.out.println("========= ACCESSION ACKNOWLEDGE CHART SERVICE LOGIC called =========" );
        
         //model.addAttribute("loadLabChartFragment", true);
        //return "./labChart";
        return "labStatistics";
        //return "labmodals/labChart::labChart";
        // return "redirect:/loadlabChart";
    }
```

the form submission will work if i am loading the page with the same controller name. For example if i load labChart.html page the form will fetch data from th:action="/labChat" and return to labChart. but if i executing /labChart in labStatistics.html The fragment will be loaded without the form getting submitted.